# How is the menu for the Vaadin 7 sampler done?

Tags: vaadin

The sampler demo for vaadin 7 is driven by a menu that pops up when the user clicks a hamburger button.

Although the sampler demo has some source code for examples, it doesn't provide the source of the demo itself.  I'm trying to figure out how to recreate that menu.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done using only CSS and changing some class attribute on button click. Here is a very simplified example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: green;
    right: -200px;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.box_t {top: 0}
.box_b {top: 40%}
.box2_t {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(-20deg);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(-20deg);
}
.box2_b {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(20deg);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(20deg);
}
</style>
<script type=text/javascript>
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("ka_t").className = "box box_t box2_t";
    document.getElementById("ka_b").className = "box box_b box2_b";
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', changeClass);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
    <button id=button>Close</button>
    <div id=ka_t class="box box_t"></div>
    <div id=ka_b class="box box_b"></div>
</body>
</html>
```